# Delay initial D3 rendering until calculations are complete

Tags: javascript, meteor, d3.js

I'm working with d3.js in Meteor and rendering a simple shape that depends on a single value from the result of a series of functions.

Upon running the calculations for the first time, the value appears elsewhere on the page after a second delay, but the shape will not render.

My console shows a series of error messages saying

```
"Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined" that refer to the functions.
```

But the calculations are running fine so these errors must be thrown before the functions are complete.

After refreshing the browser, the shape renders and I am able to update as needed.

This actually worked fine in an earlier version, but I have added some complexity to the initial calculations so I'm wondering if a delay is needed to allow them to complete.  Is it possible to delay the initial rendering of a D3 shape until certain calculations are complete?  I am using an autorun block for changes in the data but this isn't helping on the initial rendering.

```
Template.Val.onRendered (function () {
const self = this;

var valActive = UI._globalHelpers.resultValue();
//valActive is calculated using a series of functions
//...other variables

var barContainer = d3.select("#bar" + valId)
    .append("svg")
    .attr("id", "svg-bar");

var bar = barContainer.append("rect")
    .attr("x", startPct + "%")
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("height", 50)
    .attr("width", rangePct + "%")
    .attr("id", "bar" + valId);

self.autorun(function() {
var valActive = UI._globalHelpers.resultValue();
//valActive is calculated using a series of functions
//...other variables

    barContainer.select("#bar" + valId)
        .transition()
        .duration(250)
        .attr("x", startPct + "%")
        .attr("y", 0)
        .attr("height", 50)
        .attr("width", rangePct + "%");
    });
});
```

EDIT: additional code for calculations:

```
getAverageVal = function(array) {
//calculates average of an array of ratios stored in Valuation document
};

getMedianVal = function(array) {
//calculates median of an array of ratios stored in Valuation document
};

getValAll = function(valuationId) {
//creates object of all average and median ratios
//calls getMedianVal() and getAverageVal()
};

getVal = function(valuationId) {
//selects average or median
//calls getValAll()
};

getResults = function(chartId, valuationId){
//creates object of all valuations (company data * ratio)
//calls getVal()
};

Template.registerHelper('resultValue',function(chartId, valuationId){
//selects one valuation
//calls getResults()
});
```

Comment: The simplest solution of you problem is adding checks in helpers, so helper's function code will be executed only if used value is defined. Also, the good idea will be to move data loading and calculations into onCreated and keep D3 related code in onRendered.

Comment: Thanks Antoine.  Can you clarify what you mean by adding checks to helpers?  Also, in the second part, do you mean to define a helper in Template.Val.onCreated and then refer to that within the D3 code?  rather than referring to the global helper?

Comment: Before using values that causing exceptions ensure they are defined, so your helper will not crash if they aren't. I cannot tell what exactly to write because I don't know what `UI._globalHelpers.resultValue();`. Is it reactive?

Comment: @Tdm, should be.  I added code above to explain the progression in calculations that leads to `resultValue()`.  Should checks be put into each function?  Or just in the `resultValue` helper?  I am getting errors that reference all the items above.

Comment: putting it into resultValue should be enough. You should ensure you have all require data before calling `getResults`

Comment: Any chance you have an example?  Not sure how to write that check.

Comment: All set!  Was able to add `if` statements throughout and the shape now renders on initial load.  I get a long list of `d3.js:7230 Error: <rect> attribute x: Expected length, "NaN%".` console errors now, but will figure that out separately.  Thanks!